# Problems with grpc connection using ssl

Tags: java, openssl, ssl-certificate, grpc, grpc-java

I am currently new in grpc.
I wanted to provide ssl for  my grpc server
the javav code for starting looks like this:

```
InputStream publicKey = ServerStarter.class.getResourceAsStream("/my-public-key-cert.pem");
InputStream privateKey = ServerStarter.class.getResourceAsStream("/my-private-key.pem");
SslContext sslContext = GrpcSslContexts.forServer(publicKey, privateKey).build();
Server server = NettyServerBuilder.forPort(5555)
                    .sslContext(sslContext)
                    .addService(new RedirectService())
                    .intercept(new AuthorizationInterceptor())
                    .build();
server.start();
```

SSL certificates were generated with openssl. And here how openssl command looks like:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout ./grpc-server/src/main/resources/my-private-key.pem -out ./grpc-server/src/main/resources/my-public-key-cert.pem -days 365 -nodes -subj "/CN=192.168.88.132" -addext "subjectAltName = DNS.1:192.168.88.132, DNS.2:localhost"
```

Server runs fine.
But I can't connect to server.
My clients code looks like this:

```
InputStream certificate = GalamatClient.class.getResourceAsStream("/my-public-key-cert.pem");
SslContext context = GrpcSslContexts.forClient().trustManager(certificate).build();
ManagedChannel channel = NettyChannelBuilder.forTarget("192.168.88.132:5555")
                .sslContext(context)
                .build();
GreetingServiceGrpc.GreetingServiceBlockingStub stub = GreetingServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel)
GreetingService.GreetingRequest request = GreetingService.GreetingRequest.newBuilder().setMessage("Hi").build();
GreetingService.GreetingResponse response = stub.greet(request);
channel.shutdownNow();
```

And when I try to run client next Error occurs:

```
Exception in thread "main" io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAVAILABLE: io exception
Channel Pipeline: [SslHandler#0, ProtocolNegotiators$ClientTlsHandler#0, WriteBufferingAndExceptionHandler#0, DefaultChannelPipeline$TailContext#0]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.toStatusRuntimeException(ClientCalls.java:262)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.getUnchecked(ClientCalls.java:243)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls.blockingUnaryCall(ClientCalls.java:156)
    at com.example.GreetingServiceGrpc$GreetingServiceBlockingStub.recognize(SpeechRecognitionGrpc.java:246)
    at com.example.main(Client.java:59)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: General OpenSslEngine problem
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.handshakeException(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1772)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.wrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:777)
    at javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.wrap(SSLEngine.java:509)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrap(SslHandler.java:1079)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.wrapNonAppData(SslHandler.java:970)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1443)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1275)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1322)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names matching IP address 192.168.88.132 found
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchIP(HostnameChecker.java:168)
    at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:94)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:459)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:440)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:261)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:144)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.checkServerTrusted(OpenSslTlsv13X509ExtendedTrustManager.java:223)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext$ExtendedTrustManagerVerifyCallback.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslClientContext.java:261)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext$AbstractCertificateVerifier.verify(ReferenceCountedOpenSslContext.java:698)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.internal.tcnative.SSL.readFromSSL(Native Method)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.readPlaintextData(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:596)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1203)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1325)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$1.unwrap(SslHandler.java:201)
    at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1380)
    ... 21 more
    Suppressed: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.sslReadErrorResult(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1288)
        at io.grpc.netty.shaded.io.netty.handler.ssl.ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.unwrap(ReferenceCountedOpenSslEngine.java:1249)
        ... 24 more
```

Error says that I don't provide needed Ip in subject alternative names:

```
No subject alternative names matching IP address 192.168.88.132 found
```

but I provided it in command of creation certificate.
I will apreciate if you could help with that.

Comment: You used `-addext ...DNS.1:192.168.88.132...` but it should be `...IP.1:192.168.88.132...`. DNS names and IP addresses are different.

Comment: Yes, it realy helped

Answer (score 0):

Use [overrideAuthority(String authority)](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannelBuilder.html#overrideAuthority-java.lang.String-) to match what the certificate has in its SAN. Use an OpenSsl command to display what you have in your server cert.